# How can I decrypt a LUKS-encrypted ext4 drive by Windows based software?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, disk-encryption

I encrypt my HDD in Ubuntu.
Now I want to access my HDD in Windows too. 
**Is there any way in Windows to decrypt an ext4 LUKS-encrypted drive?**

Comment: Are you referring to eCryptFS, or LUKS, or the new ext4 built-in encryption feature?

Comment: It's LUKS. I set password protection while formatting HDD.

Comment: Then it's not ext4-encrypted, it's only ext4-formatted – but LUKS-encrypted.

Comment: I'm sorry; I didn't know that. Then what should I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using LUKS, it can be accessed using [LibreCrypt](https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt/releases) (a sequel to [FreeOTFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeOTFE)). This will unlock the LUKS volume, but to make Windows understand ext4 you will still need an ext4 driver such as [ext4fsd](https://www.ext2fsd.com/).

However, this combination used to work in Windows XP, but both tools are somewhat unmaintained and may not work on recent Windows versions today. For a shared disk you should instead switch to NTFS or exFAT filesystem, with either VeraCrypt or BitLocker for disk encryption.

(Ubuntu supports NTFS via the ntfs-3g driver. You can unlock VeraCrypt on Linux either via cryptsetup as a "tcrypt" disk or by installing the VeraCrypt software itself, and BitLocker disks can be opened via dislocker.)

Comment: Actually, I've motivated myself to use Ubuntu. And that's why I switch to Ext4 filesystem. It seems pretty good to me than NTFS or FAT. But, truly speaking,  sometimes I need Windows. And now I need just an at-least combination.

Comment: If you run Windows in a VM (and AFAIK, if you got a PC with a valid OEM Windows licence, you can install a legit copy of Windows in a VM), then you can access the Linux files from the VM (unencrypted by the Linux host).